# Run a web socket on Cloud Functions for Firebase?

Tags: sockets, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Hello I actually have a REST api running on Cloud Functions for Firebase using http request, but now I need to sync the data on real time requesting to the functions. I read something about web sockets.

Is there a way to run a web socket on Cloud Functions for Firebase?

Comment: You might want to look into an upcoming websockets feature for Cloud Run: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-run-gets-websockets-http-2-and-grpc-bidirectional-streams

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is not going to be a good fit for Cloud Functions. Websockets rely on long-lived connections to the same server over time; Cloud Functions are ephemeral compute instances that are spun down when there's no traffic. There's no way to force or guarantee that a Cloud Function will keep running or hold a connection open indefinitely.

I would encourage you to investigate using the Firebase Realtime Database as a conduit here instead of trying to add realtime to Cloud Functions.

Comment: I am making an app for orders similar to uber, but drivers should show them the orders that are available, I was thinking of using geofire in the client to show the generated orders near their area with a fixed radio, but if it does not make an order in A certain time should show them to people who are further away too.

Comment: I think that it need controled by the server, or there is a way to do all on the client.

Comment: You could use GeoFire to get all open orders in a broad-ish area, then use client-side filtering to hide orders based on age and distance.

Comment: Is this still a situation? Came here wondering if cloud function can host Apollo Server supporting subscription which needs a websocket.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh  have you taken a look at this ?
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-websockets-and-session-affinity

Comment: The App Engine flexible environment is quite different from Cloud Functions -- critically, there is always at least one instance running. This makes it usable for long-running connections like web sockets, but also means that there is a cost floor.

Comment: Cloud Functions are not as ephemeral as they used to be: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/min-instances

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is possible now in the 2nd generation Firebase functions (V2). What follows is a minimal proof of concept to keep it short.

Here is the Firebase functions index file. You could think of this as the 'server'. In a real case you may need to adjust the function timeout, among other things.

```
import * as functionsV2 from "firebase-functions/v2";
import {WebSocketServer} from "ws";

let server; // http.Server
const wss = new WebSocketServer({noServer: true});

wss.on("connection", (ws) => {
  ws.on("message", (message: string) => {
    functionsV2.logger.log(`Received: ${message}`);
  });
  ws.send("Hello from the server!");
});

export const websocketTest = functionsV2.https.onRequest(
  (req, res) => {
    const reqServer = req.socket.server;
    if (reqServer === server) return;
    server = reqServer;

    server.on("upgrade", (request, socket, head) => {
      wss.handleUpgrade(request, socket, head, (ws) => {
        wss.emit("connection", ws, request);
      });
    });

    // server.emit("request", req, res); // this is not sufficient
    res.setHeader("Retry-After", 0).status(503).send("Websockets now ready");
  });
```

This may be optionally prepended to the Firebase functions index file if you do not want to deal with retries.

```
import http from "http";

// called at file scope: eliminates retry even on wake (surprisingly)
function initialRequest() {
  const req = http.request({hostname: "127.0.0.1", port: 8080,
    path: "/", method: "GET"});
  req.end();
}
initialRequest();
```

This is a sample websocket client node.js file for testing and demonstration purposes. You could also do something like this in a browser instead.

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

// NOTE: it is wss:// on the next line, not https://
const url = 'wss://<ENTER THE FULL DOMAIN NAME OF YOUR FUNCTION DEPLOY URL>';
let retryCount = 0;
const maxRetries = 3;

function connectWebSocket() {
  const ws = new WebSocket(url);

  ws.on('open', function open() {
    ws.send('Hello from client!');
  });

  ws.on('message', function incoming(data) {
    console.log('Received from server:', data);
  });

  ws.on('error', function error(err) {
    if (String(err).includes('503') && retryCount < maxRetries) {
      retryCount++;
      console.log(`Retrying connection attempt ${retryCount}...`);
      connectWebSocket();
    } else {
      console.error('websockets error:', err);
    }
  });
}

connectWebSocket();
```

To deploy the function do the following in your functions directory, and then copy out the function url's fully qualified domain name--everything but the https:// part--and paste it into the client script above.

```
$ firebase deploy --only functions:websocketTest

...lots of output skipped...
i  functions: updating Node.js 18 (2nd Gen) function websocketTest(us-central1)...
✔  functions[websocketTest(us-central1)] Successful update operation.
Function URL (websocketTest(us-central1)):  // line break added for readability
  https://websockettest-<YOUR PROJECT HASH>-<TWO CHAR REGION CODE>.a.run.app
```

Once you paste in the function deployment URL sans https:// into the client script, when you execute it you will see the following almost instantly.

```
$ node ws-client.js 
Retrying connection attempt 1...
Received from server: Hello from the server!
```

In the cloud function logs you will see something like the following. Note, the 61s does not have anything to do with how long it takes the server and client hellos to be exchanged, which happens and gets logged almost instantly. The 61 seconds I believe is how long the web socket connection remains alive (which in turn is related to the function timeout, which you may adjust).

```
Cloud Run v1 websockettest ...
Cloud Functions UpdateFunction us-central1:websocketTest ...
GET 503 25 ms Unknown https://websockettest-<HASH>-<CODE>.a.run.app/
GET 101 61 s Unknown https://websockettest-<HASH>-<CODE>.a.run.app/
Received: Hello from client!
```

Further discussions--such as syncing instances via RTDB or Redis, setting min/max instances, increasing concurrency, changing timeouts--are left as an exercise to the reader, as are different methods of initiating the connection in the first place. This answer is just to show that it is in fact possible to do websockets with Firebase functions and to be a reminder to myself and others going forward about one way to do it.

Comment: Is it really possible creating a presistent fucntion in Firebase functions? And what about the cost? The websocket should be alive all the time. I think the cost would be very expensive

Comment: But I can't deploy that sample code. The error says 'Got response code 400; body Failed to generate manifest from function source: SyntaxError: Invalid URL: [object Object]'

Comment: @J.Dragon if you put a repository online somewhere I can take a look

Comment: Actually the first problem is importing 'ws'. I installed ws by 'npm install ws'. and imported it by 'const {WebSocketServer} = require('ws');'.

It cause an error 'The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable.'

Is it allowed to use the 'ws' package in Firebase Functions?

Comment: @J.Dragon The client is just something I ran using node on my own machine. My real app was a browser (which uses a different package built into browsers directly). Firebase functions get turned into containers, and their job is to listen to and serve incoming traffic when triggered. So, if you want to run the client as a cloud function also (not sure why), you will need to make a function that will trigger the client so that it can then turn around and call the sample websocket server I gave.

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically you could use two different layers: one to manage the websocket connections and another layer to handle the data processing.

The websocket layer will *not* be Cloud Functions, but a Docker container running Push Pin in Cloud Run and that’ll route HTTP calls to your Cloud Functions to do the actual data processing.

Comment: how would this work? cloud run doesn't have support for ingress web-socket messages.

Comment: As of early 2021, Cloud Run websockets are in beta. https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/websockets

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using an Apigee Java callout, where the Java (if needed) calls a Cloud Function. See https://cloud.google.com/apigee/docs/api-platform/develop/how-create-java-callout