# Is Firebase Server Functions can serve WebSockets server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, websocket, google-cloud-functions

I've been tried to push my server config for basic Chat Server based on `WebSockets` (`ws` package) on Firebase storage. In fact, once pushed, I've faced one problem - my WebSocket server is always going to `200` state, instead of `101` on each page load response.

Can someone explain to me why or perhaps it's a problem due to Firebase & WebSocket collision?

P.S.
 Firebase functions/storage/hosting are enabled of course.

Thanks.

My server config:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const port = 80 || process.env.PORT;
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port });

// ...some logic here

wss.on('open', () => {
  wss.send('something');
});

wss.on('connection', ws => {
  // ...some logic here

  ws.on('message', payload => {
     // ...some logic here
  });

  ws.on('close', () => {
     // ...some logic here
  });

  ws.on('error', event => {
    // ...some logic here
  });
});
```

My Client WebSockets config:

```
const setupSocket = (dispatch, username) => {
  const socket = new WebSocket('wss://firebase_app_domain_name:80');

  // ...some logic here

  return socket;
};
```

Comment: Cloud Functions can only be used for short-lived pieces of code. Keeping an open socket-connection doesn't match that use-case, so won't usually work well on Cloud Functions. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45741284/run-a-web-socket-on-cloud-functions-for-firebase

Comment: Thanks. So sad news anyway...