# WebSocket connection failed on Firebase hosted app

Tags: firebase, websocket, firebase-hosting

I want to use WebSockets to communicate between a web app and a game created in Unity.
I've created a simple chat app on both platforms and can communicate between them using an open WebSocket connection when I'm hosting the app locally.

Here's a short video of the app in action: https://gfycat.com/organicscholarlydeviltasmanian

However, when the app is hosted using Firebase Hosting, I get the error: **WebSocket connection to 'wss://trainscape-app.web.app/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200**

This is the line that throws the error, in a simple index.html function:

```
ws = new WebSocket(location.origin.replace(/^http/, 'ws'));
```

Does Firebase Hosting not support WebSockets in this way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run a web socket on Cloud Functions for Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45741284/run-a-web-socket-on-cloud-functions-for-firebase)

Answer (score 0):

replace the line

```
ws = new WebSocket(location.origin.replace(/^http/, 'ws'));
```

with

```
ws = new WebSocket(location.origin.replace(/^http/, 'wss'));
```

build your web app and deploy again to firebase, it should work now.

Thanks