# Is it possible to use Websockets on Cloud Functions 2nd gen?

Tags: firebase, websocket, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run

I heard that Cloud Functions 2nd gen is built on top of Cloud run which supports Websockets.
Does this mean that Cloud Functions 2nd gen can also handle Websockets?

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-run-gets-websockets-http-2-and-grpc-bidirectional-streams

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-functions-2nd-generation-now-generally-available

Comment: Why don't you give it a try, and if you have a problem, post your code with debugging information?

Comment: If you do end up trying, please report your feedback. I am about to try the same thing in the upcoming weeks.

Comment: I highly doubt this will work. Cloud Functions supports event-based actions that can be triggered in various ways. Whereas with web sockets, it supports bidirectional messages which Cloud Functions does not support.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so.

Cloud Functions are a FAAS, fully on-demand serverless. The purpose of a function is to come to life when an event occurs (pub/sub trigger, http request, etc), perform some compute logic and than die.

Web sockets do require a connection alive, so Cloud Functions don't fit well for that.

Go for Cloud Run (low learning curve  coming from functions - no docker knowledge required) or investigate the option to use Firebase Datastore to have client/server read/write and stay in synch (even easier then web socket).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to use websockets with Firebase functions v2. The key is to use `onRequest` and pull the server from `req.socket.server` so that you can make the call to `server.on("update", ...)`. The client will also need a retry mechanism for the first call or you can insert a file scope priming function that will cause the `server.on("update", ...)` listener to be attached before the real client call arrives. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/77153547/581848 for further details.